# Showing Program Compatibility Assistant (PCA) warning consistently

Tags: windows, installation

During the installation/uninstall of our SW package (app/driver) on a Windows 8 system, I get the Program Compatibility Assistant (PCA) warning "Did this program work correctly?"

There are 2 choices:
1. Yes this program worked correctly
2. No launch the troubleshooter

Installation/Uninstall are both successful even with the warning.

I need to get this warning removed.  The problem is that this issue is not reproducible consistently, so it happens sometimes and doesn't happen other times.  Also it can vary from machine to machine.

I am trying some solutions to the issue that I read on this forum and others (including a application manifest, etc), but I need to make sure that the issue is reproducible every single time to confirm that the fix is working or not.

Is there way to make the warning appear consistently on every install/uninstall?
Does Windows saves the app (probably somewhere in the registry) and doesn't show the warning on a subsequent install/uninstall if it is the same app.

Comment: This is a wild guess, but does your program have a manifest and does it declare itself compatible with Windows-8?  (both should be 'yes')

Comment: No, currently it doesn't have a manifest. I was planning to add one but since the issue is not reproducible consistently I can't claim that adding manifest fixed it.